# Break statement not working

Tags: c++, break

This program should store the number of characters of name in the variable str_length (where name < 50 characters terminated by a ".") I'm baffled as to why this code only spits out the first character, meaning it breaks from the loop when i = 0, for a name such as "Jonathan." Shouldn't it parse through the string until it finds the ".", only then breaking from the for loop?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

 string name;
 int str_length;

 cout << "What's your name" << endl;

 cin >> name;

 for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
 {
     cout << name[i];
     if (name[i] == '.')
        str_length = i;
        break;         
 }

 cout << endl;

 system("PAUSE");

 return 0;  
 }
```

Comment: Indentation is meaningless in C++.  You forgot `{}` around the body of the `if`.

Comment: You are reinventing string's find method, though. Also the header to include for `std::string` is `<string>`. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Comment: Also you shouldn't assume that the input is at least 50 characters. The string can have any size, and the `size()` method tells you that.

Comment: don't forget to accept one of the answers you got

Answer (score 5):

You have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    cout << name[i];
    if (name[i] == '.')
       str_length = i;
       break;         
}
```

Which is actually:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    cout << name[i];

    if (name[i] == '.')
    {
       str_length = i;
    }

    break;         
}
```

You want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    cout << name[i];
    if (name[i] == '.')
    {
       str_length = i;
       break;  
    }       
}
```

You are `break`ing at the end of each loop.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `{}` around `if` condition. So `break` is executed without any condition, hence the loop is exited in the first iteration itself.

Answer (score 0):

This demonstrates the danger of not using braces even for one line if statements.  I suspect you did this:

```
 if (name[i] == '.')
    str_length = i;
```

and then added the `break` later.  If you had done this:

```
 if (name[i] == '.') { 
    str_length = i;
 }
```

up front, it would have been natural to add the break inside the curly braces, and you wouldn't have had the bug.

Comment: Ah, the subtleties of programming... Thanks guys, it was a very asinine error.

Comment: Not asinine!  But avoidable through better practices - always use curly braces, even for one-liners so your code is easily modifiable.